# load a heavy view gradually

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>
    Index</h2>
@{
    using (var db = new PNUBOOKIR.Models.KowsarSiteEntities())
    {
        var queries = from n in db.vwGood
                      select n;
    <table>
          foreach (var q in queries)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @q.GoodCode
                </td>
                <td>
                    @q.GoodName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @q.GoodExplain1
                </td>
            </tr>                
        }
    </table>                    
    }    
}
```

queries.Count() is 4,000,000. but I don't want any pager how I can set it to load gradually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not page it like twitter/slashdot? (A "Load More" button or using ajax to load more on the fly)

Comment: Right. You could paginate it that way, rather than page1, page2, page3, etc... If users want more, have them click more. Don't output 4M records at once. :-)

Comment: Oh right! I take it they removed the button in favor of detecting the position in the window and loading what followed using ajax. See slashdot for an example with a button.

Comment: Dunno about the C# part, but here's the JS part: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/scrollPagination

Comment: I have downloaded this but there is a problem because if "democontent.html" is heavy so the page will load very slowly there is jquery method .ajax which gets the content but it gets all of the content in fact in this example we can see paging technic but there is no any loader request to server and get content.

Comment: I like server-side scroll paging now all of data load by $.ajax